# Unable to select Azure container registry while creating Azure container instance resource type

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances, azure-container-registry

I created an Azure Container Registry and added image to it.

[image]

Using the same resource group as Azure Container Registry, I am trying to add an Azure Container instance resource type. Both the resources are in same resource group. From the Registry dropdown, I am unable to select any registry as it is empty. **Do I need to add any permission explicitly ?**

[image]

Comment: Can you check whether The Azure Container Registry has Public Access set to 'All Networks' ? and also do you have access to pull the image from the container registry ? If not refer to this documentation about the different role and permissions for [Azure ACR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-roles?tabs=azure-cli)

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MSFT: yes the public access is set to `All Networks`. I am able to pull the image using admin user. At this moment as an alternate, while working with `Container instance` I selected `Image source` as `other registry` and used Azure Container Registery as the source and was able to access image using uid, pwd and login server info.

Answer (score 0):

**I tried to reproduce the issue in my environment and got the below output**

***I have pulled the image from Docker hub***

example image I am using

```
     docker pull httpd
```

[image]

***Created the container registry with name "NEWIMAGE"***

[image]

***I have tagged the image for determine where to push the image using below command***

```
docker tag <image_name> registry_login_server(newimage.azurecr.io)/image
```

***Pushed the image into container registry***

```
docker push registry_login_server/image
```

[image]

***While pushing the image to container registry if you get any error like  below***

[image]

***We have to login to registry server using below commands***

```
docker login login_server_container_registry
username:XXXXXX
password:XXXXXX
```

***Before creating the container instance I have enabled the admin
user access keys***

[image]

***After that created the the container instance with same Resource Group***

[image]

***Note: we will get the issue because of two reasons***

1). We have to tag the image before pushing into container registry

2). We have to enable the admin user access keys in the container registry.